# How to store the current date and message id in Mule 4 variable?

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule4

In my case, I'm doing a **migration from Mule 3 to Mule 4.**

I want to store the current date and message id in **mule 4 variables.**

**Date** formate is current date in **"yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"**

**Message_id** is date ++ (random id (size is 6 characters))

code in mule 3:

```
<set-variable variableName="messageDateF" value="#[server.dateTime.format('yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS')]" doc:name="set messageDateF"/>
<set-variable variableName="messageId" value="#[flowVars.messageDateF]#[UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace('-', '').substring(0,5)]" doc:name="set messageId"/>
```

Expected output:

> 20220202024435724ddebd

Please assist me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the equivalent set-variable for Mule 4.3. Note that I only used one variable. You can separate into two variables if really need both.

```xml
<set-variable variableName="messageId" value="#[now() as String {format: "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"} ++ (uuid() replace ("-") with "")[0 to 5]]" doc:name="set messageId"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Hello In mule4 we use DWL so you can replace your code in Mule 4 using transform message and set output as variable with name "messageId"

Note: I am using 4.4.0 mule runtime, as substring Introduced in DataWeave version 2.4.0. as per official document link

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Strings
output application/json
var messageDateF = now() as String {format: "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"}
var messageId= messageDateF ++ "" ++ substring ((uuid() replace ("-") with ""),0,5)
---
messageId
```

[image]

Comment: here is some official document for function that i used in my answer as i was not able to add it in my answer (somehow i was getting some error) 
https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-strings-functions-substring
https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-uuid
https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.3/dataweave-cookbook-format-dates

Comment: I'm just copy-pasting but it shows an error: Unable to resolve reference to: "substring". in dataweave 2.0.

Comment: messageId ' has errors: Unable to resolve reference of substring. at 5 : 5" showing postman while testing..

Comment: hello Codey_08, which runtime are you using? i am using 4.4.0 as substring Introduced in DataWeave version 2.4.0. as per official document link

Comment: Hi, Anurag Sharma.I'm using Mule runtime 4.3. How to update the version of the dataweave component?

Comment: you need to update mule runtime that will update your  DataWeave version bydefault.

go to help-->Install New Software--> then select Mule Runtimes for Anypoint Studio - https://studio.mulesoft.org/s3/studio-runtimes/ in workWith and select runtime 4.4.0

it is like installing a new software. so after this it will restart the studio. then after starting back you need to deploy the code using 4.4.0

Comment: I appreciate your response, Anurag Sharma.